# Bonded Network on Server 19.10 intermittent DHCP and connectivity

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp

I got a new toy (HP Server) and I thought I would take 19.10 for a spin.

Did a very basic install and asked it to bond my 4 NICs. Set up DHCP and set a reservation on my router for 192.168.1.109. It took some trickery to get the server to change its address to the new reservation, it kept asking for the original reservation (.118 or something), but eventually I got it moved over. All I did was clear the dhcp reservations file, release dhcp, reboot the router and run DHCP again. Fine.

So now the system is up and running but I didn't have any DNS lookups working :-/

Ran dhclient -v -4 and DNS started working again.

However, after a little while, DNS stops working again... I can get in over SSH, the network is online, but can't get to anything by name. created a script to simply run dhclient when I log in to get DNS working. Fine.

Next, I decide to throw some VMs on it, get KVM and virt-manager installed and all that is needed to make that work, fire up a new VM, and now networking gets even weirder...

I'm using network bridging on the VM guest so it's on my router with my server. Guest works great - no issues.

Now, however, the host is trying to route everything to the VMs WAN (192.168.1.147). When I turn off the guest, it is back to how it was before.

Now, if I leave it sit long enough, the HOST network stops responding at all (can't SSH). If I go pull the 2 of 4 bonded NICs I'm using and plug them back in (can be one at a time so that the guest stays online even) it comes back online, I run dhclient and we're back to "normal".

So, this netplan thing is all new to me and I'm lost.

How do I get a stable host network on this thing?

Here is my /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    bonds:
        bond0:
            dhcp4: true
            interfaces:
            - enp2s0f0
            - enp2s0f1
            - enp3s0f0
            - enp3s0f1
            parameters:
                mode: balance-rr
    ethernets:
        enp2s0f0: {}
        enp2s0f1: {}
        enp3s0f0: {}
        enp3s0f1: {}
    version: 2
```

Here is my network section of my /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/50-curtin-networking.cfg:

```
network:
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: true
      interfaces:
      - enp2s0f0
      - enp2s0f1
      - enp3s0f0
      - enp3s0f1
      parameters:
        mode: balance-rr
  ethernets:
    enp2s0f0: {}
    enp2s0f1: {}
    enp3s0f0: {}
    enp3s0f1: {}
  version: 2
```

And here is my "ip a":

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:fe:2c:df:f0:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp2s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:fe:2c:df:f0:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp3s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:fe:2c:df:f0:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp3s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:fe:2c:df:f0:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:fe:2c:df:f0:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.109/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:91:19:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: virbr0-nic: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:91:19:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: macvtap0@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 500
    link/ether 52:54:00:d8:23:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.147/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic macvtap0
       valid_lft 83997sec preferred_lft 83997sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fed8:2336/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Any ideas how I:
a) get the bond0 to stay the default route?
b) get DNS client to stay up?
c) get it to not sit at the "waiting for networking" screen when the OS is loading for, like, 3 minutes?

Sorry, I've been looking around but can't find anyone else with these issues... Fresh install and everything - figured this would be fool proof...

Thanks,
--mobrien

Comment: Sorry... Fixed it in the title - not sure how I messed that up - started on 8.04 back in the day and I guess the versions all kind of start to look the same at some point.

Comment: Hmmm... Just messing with the 50-curtin-networking.cfg file yesterday and returning it back, restarting some services, and it has been running with DNS working for about 24 hours now... I don't trust it, yet, though because I don't know why it started working with the same config anyway... I appreciate any thoughts on this as I learn this new way of doing networking in Ubuntu.

Comment: Went back to same behavior... Not sure why... Shouldn't networking work out-of-the-box on a pretty standard server with a stock install??